# How to get 2D array rows to print as columns side by side?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

This is my attempt at solving the problem.  I want the output in the console window to read the 3 rows of the 2D array as 3 columns with space between the columns.

```
for(int l = 0; l < studentsAnsNew.length; l++) {
        for(int m = 0; m < studentsAnsNew[l].length; m++) {
            System.out.print("  " + studentsAnsNew[l][m] + "\n");
        }
        System.out.print("\t");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the existing rows as columns and vice versa, change

```
System.out.print("  " + studentsAnsNew[l][m] + "\n");
```

to

```
System.out.print("  " + studentsAnsNew[m][l] + "\n"); // notice the swapped indexes
```

Edit : Do take care of changing the bounds of array as well, assuming in your code :

```
int rows = studentsAnsNew.length;
int columns = studentsAnsNew[0].length;
```

the loop shall now become:

```
for(int l = 0; l < columns; l++) {
    for(int m = 0; m < rows; m++) {
        System.out.println("  " + studentsAnsNew[m][l]); // changed to println
    }
    System.out.print("\t");
}
```

Comment: I recommend changing the loop bounds too

Comment: @harold Updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the section of code in a while loop. Create a variable to increment. Increment this variable each loop and use this as a reference in the array. Also, remove the tab space. Example:

```
int temp = 0;
while(temp<3){
    for(int l = 0; l < studentsAnsNew.length; l++) {
        System.out.print("  " + studentsAnsNew[l][temp]);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    temp++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work either.  I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowz = 0;
int questionNumber = 1;
for(int col = 0; col < studentsAnsNew[rowz].length; col++) {
    System.out.printf("%2d)%2s\t\t", questionNumber, studentsAnsNew[rowz][col]);
    System.out.printf("%3d)%2s\t\t", questionNumber, studentsAnsNew[rowz +1][col]);
    System.out.printf("%3d)%2s\n", questionNumber, studentsAnsNew[rowz + 2][col]);
    questionNumber++;
}
```

Comment: This is one correct way of doing it.  Not sure if it is the most efficient though.